# Clicking a div hides div and replaces another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I am trying to create a video player where if you click an image it swaps the image for a youtube video. The code was working fine until i wanted put a div over the top for a player button.

Now, of course, that button is in the way and won't recognize the click event. How do i know when you click the "play" div it hides that div and swaps the other div image for the youtube video.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#play').click(function(){
        $('#play').hide();
        $('img').function () {
            video = '<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
            $(this).replaceWith(video);
    });
});
```

I am still really new to jQuery and don't understand exactly how the layout and function calling works. Your insight will really help!

Thanks :)

Comment: HTML, please, and maybe a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Try $('img').html('<iframe src="' + $(this).attr('data-video') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/tvyfxey6/

The idea is to click the play div and it to change the picture to a YouTube irame, while at the same time hiding the play div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/tvyfxey6/6/

```
 $('#play').on('click', function(evt) {
         alert('click'); 
     $('#play').hide();
      $('#img').hide();
     $('#video').html('<iframe src="' + $('#video').attr('data-video') + '" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');

 });
```

Comment: Remove the alert statement of course. I just want you to see that it's triggering.

Comment: That is working great for a single video but when I want to videos of the same code it only works on the first one.

When trying to change to work on classes and not id's its messes up completely.

I am wanting the code to work indepdently on that div that was clicked so it does affect other divs with the same classes/ids until that one is clicked. Here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/tvyfxey6/7/

Comment: Anyone got any great knowledge on this? Been trying but nothing seems to work. It just breaks the whole site.